# Find the limit of a rational function.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to figure out how can I solve this limit. It goes as follows,
$$\lim_{t\to 1} {\sqrt[3]{t} -1\over \sqrt{t}-1}$$
I tried using the conjugate but it doesn't seem to work for a cubed root expressions such as this one.

Comment: Should it be $$\lim_{\color{red}{t}\to 1}$$

Comment: set $t=x^6$ to solve the problem

Comment: Your title is misleading, since your functions is not a rational function.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $(x-1)$ and use the standard limit $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^{n} - a^{n}} {x-a} =na^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

your term is equal to $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{t}-1}{\sqrt{t}-1}=\frac{x^2-1}{x^3-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$$

Comment: You essentially raised the power of the expression until the numerator and denominator could be simplified (able to be factored)?

Comment: yes this is true

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]t-1}{\sqrt t-1}=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{s^2-1}{s^3-1}=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{(s+1)(s-1)}{(s-1)(s^2+s+1)}=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{s+1}{s^2+s+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital rule,

> $$\lim_{t\to 1} \frac{\frac{1}{3t^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt {t}}}$$$$\frac{2}{3}$$